# How to handle 404 error with jQuery $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404

To test what happens when I try to load a non-existent resource (on the same host as my web server), I set up the following code:

```
var wrongURL = "http://foo/bar.json"; // non-existent resource
$.ajax({
    url: wrongURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(jsonResponse, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $.('#divOfInterest').html("you should never see this");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $.('#divOfInterest').html("sorry, could not find URL");
    }
});
// remainder of code...
```

Instead of seeing my div show the message `sorry, could not find URL`, I get a console error:

```
GET http://foo/bar.json 404 (Not Found) - bar.json
```

Anything within the `error` call and after the `$.ajax()` block (i.e., `// remainder of code`) does not get executed

It looks like my browser (Safari 5.1.5) is getting stuck on the 404 error and leaves the function early.

How do I get to handle the error gracefully and execute the rest of my code?

Comment: It's also working on safari 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `$.('#divOfInterest')` with `$('#divOfInterest')` :D

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ua8J/

Comment: With the dots it shows the error: `XML filter is applied to non-XML value` with no output, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/SuHDP/

Comment: Yeah, that's assuming that the ajax call actually enters the callbacks. But read the question carefully: the JavaScript crashes when trying to connect to non-existent resource. Also I've managed to reproduce the error on Chrome (with correct JS) although jsFiddle works which is even stranger.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work outside of jsfiddle using the fixed code....so I guess jQuery handles the event properly then.
It looks like this is the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you need a server to actually return an error status for that error function to be run.

For instance if you request a JSON object for a non existant user on Soundcloud, you will get a 404 error returned from the server.

However of you mistype the full URI, then there is no resource returned at all, and no status code either.

Comment: Actually there is a status, it's zero. just check jqXHR.status === 0